# Running Python on a module with relative imports from another directory

Tags: python

Say that under `/path/to/foo` I have package with a python module:

```
/path/to/foo:
           | my_package
                        | __init__.py
                        | my_module.py

           | my_other_package
                        | __init__.py
                        | my_other_module.py
```

The file `my_module.py` does a relative import of `my_other_module.py` as follows:

```
  from ..my_other_package import my_other_module
```

I understand that I can do the following from the shell:

```
> cd /path/to/foo
> python -m my_package.my_module
```

But what if I don't want to change my current directory? Is there any way to run my module from the shell without having to change `PYTHONPATH`?

I tried the following:

```
python -m /path/to/foo/my_package.my_module
```

but that didn't work. I got: `Import by filename is not supported`.

Comment: Have you tried using a symlink from my_package to my_other_package/my_other_module.py?

Comment: Have you tried adding a `__init__.py` to `/path/to/foo` as well? I don't think you can do this if `foo` is not a package in itself.

Answer (score 1):

Get the relative path:

`base_path = os.path.abspath('../my_other_package/')  #or any relative directory`

append this to the system path (only temporary, will be deleted after execution):
`sys.path.append(base_path)`

import the file you need in that path:
`import my_other_module.py`

I believe it you may need a file named `__init__.py` (with nothing in it) if you wanted to import the file as `import directory.file` (correct me if I'm wrong).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python) thread shows alternate approaches.

Comment: Thanks. I have read that tampering with `sys.path` is not a good idea, but I guess this the best I could do..